# Gevent wait for jobs to finish (joinall vs wait)

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

The first documentation's [example](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example) waits for all spawned jobs to finish with:

```
gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=2)
```

However, [joinall](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.joinall) is not documented but [wait](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.wait) method is:

> Wait for objects to become ready or for event loop to finish.

Do both methods have the same functionality and only differ in their implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joinall` is documented:

> joinall(greenlets, timeout=None, raise_error=False, count=None) Wait
>   for the greenlets to finish.
>
> Parameters:
>   greenlets – A sequence (supporting len()) of greenlets to wait for.
>   timeout (float) – If given, the maximum number of seconds to wait.
>   Returns:   A sequence of the greenlets that finished before the timeout (if any) expired.

As you can see there are differences in functionalities. The biggest one is that `wait` applies to many things, whereas `joinall` only applies to greenlets. So the functionalities of `joinall` are taylored for greenlets.

Comment: Thanks for the update! [Back then](https://web.archive.org/web/20150612135103/http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.joinall), it wasn't documented :)